# Surface XML schema as UI in SharePoint 2010

Tags: xml, web-part

I have a requirement (at the least possible cost, be that custom dev or 3rd party product) to take an XML schema (which is subject to regular change) and surface a UI to this through SharePoint.

The UI cannot require manual changes when the XML schema changes.  So in some way the UI needs to be dynamically generated from the schema file.

Does anyone have any ideas, either 3rd party products that do this or else a development approach which would require the least development effort.

Your thoughts are as always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a very peculiar requirement! Why would anyone need that? :-)

I prefer creating my schemas in VS or using XSD.exe from the base of an existing XML file.

Comment: We have an externally published xsd schema which we need to ensure that our UI is generating appropriate XML files for.  To keep down costs of re-engineering the UI for every schema change the UI needs to dynamically generate according to the current schema.  Basically I need a kind of dynamic InfoPath form.  I know this is a long shot and I am guessing the answer is write it yourself, but sometimes it helps just to ask...